# Generating Functions with multiple arguments

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I want to solve the recurrence of Ackermann function using Generating Function in Mathematica.

```
GeneratingFunction[RSolve[{f[x, y] == f[x - 1, f[x, y - 1]],
f[0, y] == y + 1,f[x, 0] == f[x - 1, 1]}, 
f[x, y], x, y], x, y, n]
```

But I am not getting the result. As far as I know we can only pass 3 arguments to Generating Function but I am sending 4. Please let me know how to solve it.

P.S. I just started using Mathematica. So please suggest the solution though it is trivial.

Comment: What is the definition for `Rsolve`?

Comment: I checked this question and thought I need to use Rsolve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911900/how-to-get-the-generating-function-automatically-in-mathematica

Comment: SiMemon, notice that the built-in *Mathematica* function is `RSolve`, notice the uppercase `S`.

Comment: I changed it. But still I am getting error as "RSolve::nestdv: "The expression f[x,-1+y] has nested dependent variables. "

Comment: `RSolve` cannot handle nested expressions, like `f[x - 1, f[x, y - 1]]`.  Can you write your formula in another way?

Comment: @bbgodfrey As I said I am new to Mathematica, can you tell me another way to write it without using Rsolve?

Comment: Actually, I was asking whether you could write your recurrence equation in a way that does not involve nesting.  As to alternatives to `RSolve`, `RecurrenceTable` in combination with `FindSequenceFunction` sometimes works.  Here, however, `RecurrenceTable` also fails due to the nested recurrence relation.  I know how to work around that problem, but doing so is no guarantee that `FindSequenceFunction` would succeed.

Comment: By the way, I suggest you edit your question to replace `Rsolve` by `RSolve`.  You might get more help that way.

Comment: The [Ackermann-Péter function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) doesn't really admit a simpler closed form in the general case. Why would you think *Mathematica* would be capable of producing one?